# How to set a div to use certain percentage of the height, while using overflow:auto to put a scrollbar?

Tags: html, scrollbar, css

I have the following code:

```
div.leftnav {
    overflow: auto ;
    height: 50% ;
}
```

That, when I set a big div of this class, does not work (it doesn't show the scrollbar nor resize it to 50%, however it works perfectly if instead if I use

```
height: 400px ;
```

Or some other "absolute" value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

height will only work if the parent element has a height instruction as well.

So say you have really simple markup :

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="leftnav">
            really long text
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then the following CSS will work for you :

```
div.leftnav {
    overflow: auto ;
    height: 50%;
}
html, body { 
    height:100%;
}
```

You need to have height instructions all the way though. If there is a height instruction missing on one of the parent elements, then the 100% won't mean anything to the div. If you can't access all the elements down the tree, then you will need a parent element with a fixed height :

```
<div class="leftnav-container">
    <div class="leftnav">
        really long text
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you need this css :

```
div.leftnav {
    overflow: auto ;
    height: 50%;
}
div.leftnav-container {
    height : 500px;
}
```